# IE 9 Browser method setExpression

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

IE 9 does not support setExpression

```
document.documentElement.setExpression("scrollLeft", "scrollLeft=10" );
```

is there any other method is there for IE 9 in place of setExpression.

Comment: FYI I don't think IE8 supports it either. http://help.dottoro.com/ljarcrag.php - "These methods exist in version 8, but using them raises exceptions."

Answer (score 1):

Since setExpression is deprecated in IE > 7, you have no choice but to use plain javascript to set the properties you want:

```
document.getElementById('MyElementId').scrollLeft = 10;
```

Or if you want your existing code to just work without modifying it, tell Internet Explorer to use IE7 rendering (when the method still existed) using the following in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Comment: +1. But I would emphasise that it is much much better to use the standards-compliant answer, rather than compatibility mode.